# FindRoot with NIntegrate: either recursion depth exceeded or numerical integration converging too slowly

Tags: equation-solving, numerical-integration

Trying to numerically solve an equation involving an integral, either the error `Recursion depth exceeded` appears (when `AccuracyGoal->10` or smaller) or the error `Numerical integration converging too slowly` appears. In the MWE below, the functions involved are smooth, bounded and the solution for the equation is `1` (as confirmed by `Plot[{hdif[z], 0}, {z, smin, 2}]`), so there should not be difficulty numerically integrating or solving.

How to find a solution to similar equations which cannot be solved by hand analytically?

MWE

```
Clear[smin, smax, h, hdif]
smin = -1;
h[z_] := Exp[-z/2]
hdif[zmax_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[(Exp[z] - 1)*h[z], {z, smin, zmax}, AccuracyGoal -> 5]
smax = FindRoot[{hdif[smax] == 0}, {smax, 0, smin, Max[-smin, 1000]}]
```

Other solutions recommend increasing `AccuracyGoal` or `WorkingPrecision` (both of which I tried), cancelling periodic oscillations, integrating piecewise around points where the derivative is discontinuous (these do not apply to the function in question). 
Replacing `NIntegrate` with `Integrate` works for `h[z_] := Exp[-z/2]`, but not for functions without a closed form integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`NDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolveValue) for something like this:

```
smin = -1;
h[z_] := Exp[-z/2]
Last @ Reap[
    NDSolveValue[
        {
        int'[z] == (Exp[z] - 1) h[z], int[smin] == 0, 
        WhenEvent[int[z]==0, {"StopIntegration", Sow[z, "zmax"]}]
        },
        int,
        {z, smin, Infinity}
    ],
    _,
    #1 -> First@#2&
]
```

> {"zmax" -> 1.}